# Scanning for WiFi networks - Difference between "iw" and "iw dev"

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, iwlwifi, network-monitoring

I am curious what the "dev" addition does in terms of output results or functionality of the command.

```
sudo iw wlan0 scan
```

vs

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 scan
```

Comment: It should make you read `man iw`.